# Why does spot light light objects outside the cone?

Tags: rendering, lighting

I have a scene set up in Blender Cycles, basically two objects aligned on the X axis, but with a distance between.

I have a first spotlight lighting object 1 from the top, with the cone only large enough to light it up. The second object is quite far away, is outside the cone and spotlight radius is 0.

However, this second one still receives some light from the spotlight. Is it linked with indirect lighting?

[image: The Issue]

Comment: I'm sorry, but without pictures or the file it is hard to tell what is going on there. Which distance is between them? How far is "quite far away"? Is the spotlight shining straight down or at an angle? What shape do the objects have? Maybe it is just bounce light reflecting off the object inside the spotlight cone? Are there other objects surrounding the ones you are talking about? Any other light sources, environment lighting?

Comment: I edited the post. I don't know a lot about Blender lighting ... There are no other light sources, no environment lighting. I want the light to only affect the right object, I mean the light not affecting anything outside of the cone.

Comment: "*Why does spot light light objects outside the cone?*" https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/render_settings/indirect_lighting.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there is light bouncing of the surfaces of the floor and the body, it is not the direct spotlight which illuminates the body to the left. It is the indirect lighting reflected from the other objects. Maybe you have heard the term "global illumination" before as another name for indirect illumination.

It is meant to make scenes look more realistic since in real life, light bounces around and so everything is lit up not only by direct illumination like having a light directly shining onto the surface, but to a great part also by bounce light from the surrounding surfaces. This is what *Cycles* is good for - if you do not want that, why use it anyway? Maybe you should prefer rendering with *Eevee*.

However, if you want to get rid of the bounce light you can do this by changing some settings and getting a less realistic result.

The "least unrealistic" would be to make the floor completely black and without any glossiness, for example by giving it a material with a simple *Diffuse BSDF* set to black. This could only be problematic if you want a white floor and the body on the left will still get a little bounce lighting reflecting off the skin of the right body.

If you want a white floor but do not want it to reflect the light onto other surfaces, you could go to the floor's *Object Properties* > *Visibility* and disable the *Ray Visibility* for *Diffuse* and *Glossy*. This way the white floor which contributes most to the indirect lighting will not reflect light. But like before, the skin will still reflect light.

The most unrealistic would be to go into the scene's *Render Properties* > *Light Paths* and there under *Max Bounces* you disable *Diffuse* and *Glossy* by setting them to 0. This way no surface will reflect any light, neither floor nor skin. However, this appearance you can achieve with *Eevee* as well and you do not need to use *Cycles*.

[image: global illumination]

[image: black floor]

[image: disable floor visibility]

[image: disable max bounces]

[image: eevee render]